# How to return value from SwingWorker class and use in other class and enable MenuItem when process is done?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am using `SwingWorker` class to make a process run in another thread. What I want is, once this thread has finished processing, it should return a `String` and also it should enable a `JMenuItem`. I am using the `done()` method in the `SwingWorker` class to enable the `JMenuItem` but I  receive a `NullPinterException`. The `doInBackground()` method returns a String which I want to access in the main GUI class - `GUIMain.java`, present in the same package. How should I do that? I saw many examples which implement `done()` or `onPostExecute()` methods, but I think I am going wrong somewhere. Here is the code which I have implemented:

```
 public class GUIMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener, FocusListener, ItemListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

        private JMenuBar menuBar;    // Defined a menuBar item
        private JMenu recalibrationMenu;  // Define the recalibration menu item
        private JMenuItem CGMenuItem;
        private JMenuItem TGMenuItem;
        private JMenu viewResultsMenu;  // Define the View Results menu item
        public JMenuItem cgResults;
        public JMenuItem tgResults;    
        private JPanel TGImage;
        private JPanel TGPanel;
        private JPanel CGImage;
        private JPanel CGPanel;
        private JPanel CGRecalibrationParameters;

        private JDialog resultsParameters;
        private JLabel massPeakLabel = new JLabel("Select mass peak (m/z)");
        private JTextField massPeakField = new JTextField(5);
        private JLabel massWindowLabel = new JLabel("Mass window (Da)");
        private JTextField massWindowField = new JTextField(5);
        private float mzPeakValue;
        private float massWindowValue;
        private JButton massPeakSelectionButton = new JButton("OK");
        private JButton CloseDialogButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        private String CGRecalibratedFilesPath;
        private String TGRecalibratedFilesPath;


        /** Constructor to setup the GUI */
        public GUIMain(String title) {

            super(title);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());



            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

            // build the Recalibration menu
            recalibrationMenu = new JMenu("Recalibration");
            CGMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Crystal Growth");
            CGMenuItem.setEnabled(false); //initially disabled when app is launched
            CGMenuItem.addActionListener(this);

            TGMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Topological Greedy");
            TGMenuItem.setEnabled(false); //initially disabled when app is launched
            TGMenuItem.addActionListener(this);

            recalibrationMenu.add(CGMenuItem);
            recalibrationMenu.add(TGMenuItem);

            // build the View Results menu
            viewResultsMenu = new JMenu("View Results");
            cgResults = new JMenuItem("CG Recalibration");
            cgResults.setEnabled(false); //initially disabled when app is launched
            cgResults.addActionListener(this);
            tgResults = new JMenuItem("TG Recalibration");
            tgResults.setEnabled(false); //initially disabled when app is launched
            tgResults.addActionListener(this);

            viewResultsMenu.add(cgResults);
            viewResultsMenu.add(tgResults);

            // add menus to menubar
            menuBar.add(fileMenu);
            menuBar.add(recalibrationMenu);
            menuBar.add(viewResultsMenu);


            // put the menubar on the frame
            setJMenuBar(menuBar);      

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Exit program if close-window button clicked
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 800)); // Set the preferred window size
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public GUIMain()
        {

        } 
    }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Handle CG menu item action
            **if ((e.getSource() == CGMenuItem)) {
                RecalibrationWorker rw = new RecalibrationWorker(file,"CG");
                rw.processCompleted();
                rw.setVisible(true);
                cgResults.setEnabled(true);
            }**


            if ((e.getSource() == cgResults)) {
                viewRecalibrationResults("CG Recalibration - View Results", "CG");
            }

            if ((e.getSource() == tgResults)) {
                viewRecalibrationResults("TG Recalibration - View Results", "TG");
            }

        }


        private void viewRecalibrationResults(String dialogTitle, final String recalibrationType) {
            resultsParameters = new JDialog();
            resultsParameters.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            resultsParameters.setTitle(dialogTitle);
            GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            gc.ipady = 20;
            // gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            resultsParameters.add(massPeakLabel, gc);
            commonMassThresholdLabel.setLabelFor(massPeakField);

            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.ipady = 0;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            resultsParameters.add(massPeakField,gc);
            massPeakField.setText("");
            massPeakField.addActionListener(this);
            massPeakField.addFocusListener(this);

            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 1;
            gc.ipady = 20;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            resultsParameters.add(massWindowLabel, gc);
            massWindowLabel.setLabelFor(massWindowField);

            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.gridy = 1;
            gc.ipady = 0;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            resultsParameters.add(massWindowField,gc);
            massWindowField.setText("");
            massWindowField.addActionListener(this);
            massWindowField.addFocusListener(this);


            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 2;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            resultsParameters.add(massPeakSelectionButton, gc);

            massPeakSelectionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if ("CG".equals(recalibrationType))
                        recalibrationResults("CG");

                    else if ("TG".equals(recalibrationType))
                        recalibrationResults("TG");
                }
            });

            massPeakSelectionButton.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        if ("CG".equals(recalibrationType))
                            recalibrationResults("CG");

                        else if ("TG".equals(recalibrationType))
                            recalibrationResults("TG");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                }
            });

            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.gridy = 2;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            resultsParameters.add(CloseDialogButton,gc);
            CloseDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    resultsParameters.dispose();
                }
            });

            resultsParameters.setVisible(true);
            resultsParameters.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
            resultsParameters.setSize(270, 150);
            resultsParameters.setResizable(false);
        }
    }


public class RecalibrationWorker extends JDialog {

    private boolean isStarted = false;
    private JLabel counterLabel = new JLabel("Recalibration not yet started");
    private Worker worker = new Worker();
    private JPanel recalibrationParameters;
    private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton rawSpectra = new JRadioButton("Use raw spectra");
    private JRadioButton preprocessedSpectra = new JRadioButton("Use preprocessed spectra");
    private static float commonMassThresholdValue;
    private static float recalibrationThresholdValue;
    private static double mergeSpectraThresholdValue;
    private JLabel commonMassThresholdLabel = new JLabel("<html>Common Mass Window<br>(value between 0.01-0.9 Da)</html>");
    private JTextField commonMassThresholdField = new JTextField(String.valueOf(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            commonMassThresholdValue = Float.parseFloat(commonMassThresholdField.getText());
            recalibrationThresholdField.requestFocusInWindow();

        }
    }));
    private JLabel recalibrationThresholdLabel = new JLabel("<html>Mass threshold to recalibrate two spectra<br>(value between 0.01-0.9 Da)</html>");
    private JTextField recalibrationThresholdField = new JTextField(String.valueOf(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            recalibrationThresholdValue = Float.parseFloat(recalibrationThresholdField.getText());
            mergeSpectraThresholdField.requestFocusInWindow();

        }
    }));
    private JLabel mergeSpectraThresholdLabel = new JLabel("<html>Mass threshold to merge spectra<br>(value between 0.01-0.9 Da)</html>");
    private JTextField mergeSpectraThresholdField= new JTextField(String.valueOf(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mergeSpectraThresholdValue = Float.parseFloat(mergeSpectraThresholdField.getText());
            startButton.requestFocusInWindow();

        }
    }));
    private JTextArea recalibrationStatus = new JTextArea(7,32);
    private JScrollPane textAreaScrolling = new JScrollPane(recalibrationStatus);


    private JButton startButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Recalibrate") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!isStarted) {
                Worker w = new Worker();
                w.addPropertyChangeListener(new RecalibrationWorkerPropertyHandler(RecalibrationWorker.this));
                w.execute();
                isStarted = false;
            }
        }

    });
    private JButton stopButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Stop") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            worker.cancel(true);
        }

    });

    public File file;
    public String type;
    public String resultFilePath;


    public RecalibrationWorker(File dataFile, String recalibrationType) {

        file = dataFile;
        type = recalibrationType;

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        if("CG".equals(recalibrationType))
            setTitle("Crystal Growth Recalibration");
        else if("TG".equals(recalibrationType))
            setTitle("Topological Greedy Recalibration");

        recalibrationParameters = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        radioButtonGroup.add(rawSpectra);
        radioButtonGroup.add(preprocessedSpectra);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        recalibrationParameters.add(preprocessedSpectra,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        recalibrationParameters.add(rawSpectra,gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.ipady = 20;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        recalibrationParameters.add(commonMassThresholdLabel, gc);
        commonMassThresholdLabel.setLabelFor(commonMassThresholdField);
        commonMassThresholdField.setColumns(3);
        commonMassThresholdField.setText("");

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.ipady = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        recalibrationParameters.add(commonMassThresholdField, gc);
        commonMassThresholdField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                commonMassThresholdValue = Float.parseFloat(commonMassThresholdField.getText());
                recalibrationThresholdField.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.ipady = 20;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        recalibrationParameters.add(recalibrationThresholdLabel, gc);
        recalibrationThresholdLabel.setLabelFor(recalibrationThresholdField);
        recalibrationThresholdField.setColumns(3);
        recalibrationThresholdField.setText("");

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.ipady = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        recalibrationParameters.add(recalibrationThresholdField, gc);
        recalibrationThresholdField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                recalibrationThresholdValue = Float.parseFloat(recalibrationThresholdField.getText());
                mergeSpectraThresholdField.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.ipady = 20;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        recalibrationParameters.add(mergeSpectraThresholdLabel, gc);
        mergeSpectraThresholdLabel.setLabelFor(mergeSpectraThresholdField);
        mergeSpectraThresholdField.setText("");

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.ipady = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        recalibrationParameters.add(mergeSpectraThresholdField, gc);
        mergeSpectraThresholdField.setColumns(3);
        mergeSpectraThresholdField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                mergeSpectraThresholdValue = Double.parseDouble(mergeSpectraThresholdField.getText());
                startButton.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        recalibrationParameters.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Parameters"),
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        recalibrationParameters.add(startButton, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        recalibrationParameters.add(stopButton, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(recalibrationParameters, gc);

        textAreaScrolling.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Recalibration status"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(textAreaScrolling, gc);

        recalibrationStatus.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        recalibrationStatus.setLineWrap(true);
        recalibrationStatus.setEditable(false);

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        setSize(415, 425);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    // constructor
    public RecalibrationWorker()
    {

    }

    public float commonMassThreshold() {
        return commonMassThresholdValue;
    }

    public float recalibrationThreshold() {
        return recalibrationThresholdValue;
    }

    public double mergeSpectraThreshold() {
        return mergeSpectraThresholdValue;
    }

    protected String processCompleted() {
        return resultFilePath;
    }

    protected void processFailed() {
        System.out.println("Recalibration failed");
    }



    class Worker extends SwingWorker<String,String> {


      //  String  resultfilePath;

        @Override
        public String doInBackground() throws Exception {

            InputData inputDataObject1 = new InputData();
            if(type == "CG")
            {
                resultFilePath = inputDataObject1.startRecalibration(file, type);
                publish("Recalibration Successful!\nFiles can be found at: " + resultFilePath);
            }
            else if (type == "TG")
            {
                resultFilePath = inputDataObject1.startRecalibration(file, type);
                publish("Recalibration Successful!\nFiles can be found at: " + resultFilePath);
            }
            return resultFilePath;
        }

       public void done() {
           try {
               get();
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
       }

        @Override
        protected void process(java.util.List<String> chunks) {
            String value = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            recalibrationStatus.append("\n"+value);
            // recalibrationStatus.append(chunks.toString());
        }

    }

import javax.swing.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

/**
 * Created by localadm on 27/09/15.
 */
public class RecalibrationWorkerPropertyHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private RecalibrationWorker rwObject;

    public RecalibrationWorkerPropertyHandler(RecalibrationWorker rwObject) {
        this.rwObject = rwObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      //  System.out.println(evt.getPropertyName());
        if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            //  int value = (int) evt.getNewValue();
            // rwObject.showProgress(value);
        } else if ("state".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker) evt.getSource();
            if (worker.isDone()) {
                try {
                    worker.get();
                    System.out.println("I am here");
                    rwObject.processCompleted();
                } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                    rwObject.processFailed();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    rwObject.processFailed();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a few ways you might be able to it, you could use a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) and the `done` method to send back results when the worker is done or you could use the worker's `PropertyChangeListener` support and monitor for the `state` property and when the `state` changes to `DONE`, you would perform some other action.  The key here is you want to be notifying the instance of the object which is actually on the screen, not create a new instance which is completely unrelated

Comment: `if(type == "CG")` is not how `String` comparison works in Java, you should be using `if("CG".equals(type))` instead

Comment: [For a `PropertyChangeListener` example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125642/swingworker-in-another-swingworkers-done-method/23126410#23126410)

Comment: Based on the PropertyChangeListener example I was able to get a notification of when the process is complete. But, I am still confused and not sure as to how can I return the string and notify the GUIMain object on the screen about it to enable the JMenuItem? I updated the whole code which now includes the PropertyChangeListener.

Comment: I did something like if processCompleted is true, enable the button, in the GUIMain.java class. But, the button is enabled even before the process is complete.

Comment: Still unable to find a solution to enable the button and get a string as a return value after the process is complete :(

Comment: Did you disable the button before starting the worker?

Comment: Yes. It is disabled.

Comment: Okay, three things, 1. I don't see anywhere in your code example where you disable anything; 2. I don't see anywhere in your code example where you enable anything; 3. I what you are trying to disable/enable isn't within the code example, then you either need a reference to it or you need some kind of callback which can be notified that the process has completed (which is probably preferable)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The menuItem enable/disabled is in the mainGUI class and not in this `RecalibrationWorker` class. I am exactly looking for this call back. I tried different things like putting an `if` condition, returning a `boolean` but it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using a `JDialog` to manage the `SwingWorker`, you can actual use the modal state of the dialog to you advantage.

Essentially, when a dialog is modal, it will block the code execution where the dialog is made visible.  It will block until the dialog is hidden, at which time, the code will continue to execute.

So, you can disable the button before the dialog is made visible and re-enable it when it's closed.

[image: Worker]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Go");
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                    SomeWorkerDialog worker = new SomeWorkerDialog(TestPane.this);
                    // This is just so we can see the button ;)
                    Point point = btn.getLocationOnScreen();
                    worker.setLocation(worker.getX(), point.y + btn.getHeight());
                    worker.setVisible(true);
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class SomeWorkerDialog extends JDialog {

        private JProgressBar progressBar;
        private SomeWorkerSomeWhere worker;


        public SomeWorkerDialog(JComponent parent) {
            super(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parent), "Working Hard", DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);

            progressBar = new JProgressBar();
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

            add(progressBar, gbc);

            worker = new SomeWorkerSomeWhere();
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    String name = evt.getPropertyName();
                    switch (name) {
                        case "state":
                            switch (worker.getState()) {
                                case DONE:
                                    setVisible(false);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "progress":
                            progressBar.setValue(worker.getProgress());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    worker.execute();
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                    worker.cancel(true);
                }

            });

            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

        }

    }

    public class SomeWorkerSomeWhere extends SwingWorker {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < 100 && !isCancelled(); index++) {
                setProgress(index);
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            return "AllDone";
        }

    }

}
```

**Update**

To get the value returned by the worked, you can add a method to the dialog which returns the calculated value...

```
public String getValue() throws Exception {
    return worker.get()
}
```

So, once the dialog is closed and the execution of your code continues, you can enable the components you want and call the `getValue` method

You can also store the result when the state changes and the PropertyChangeListener is notified

Comment: Thank you, I understand your code. However when I try doing `RecalibrationWorker rw = new RecalibrationWorker(GUIMain.this, file,"CG")`, I get the following error `Error:(1220, 69) java: incompatible types: RecalibrationGUI.GUIMain cannot be converted to javax.swing.JComponent`. And, I am stuck again. Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Also, just to add some more details, the `Start` button is on my `JDialog` which should start a process and once this process is over, only then it should activate the `JMenuItem` on the `GUIMain` frame. So, still the thing remains the same, I cannot access the `JMenuItem` which has to be activated from within the `RecalibrationWorker` class and change its state.

Comment: Also, the `worker.execute()` should be called when the `startButton` on the dialog is clicked.

Comment: *"Also, just to add some more details, the Start button is on my JDialog which should start a process and once this process is over, only then it should activate the JMenuItem*" - But one assumes that the dialog is still modal...

Comment: *"Error:(1220, 69) java: incompatible types: RecalibrationGUI.GUIMain cannot be converted to javax.swing.JComponent"* - Since you've never provided any code for the GUIMain, there's little I can help you with, other then provide some component which is actually attached to the screen

Comment: *"Also, the worker.execute() should be called when the startButton on the dialog is clicked."* - Which is irrelevant, this is up to you to control.  I've just shown how you can take advantage of the modal state of the dialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90791/discussion-between-novicegeek-and-madprogrammer).