# How do I load an animated GIF within my JFrame while a long process is running?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

**Problem**
When a button is clicked, it needs to pop up a loading GIF, while a very long process is executed. This pop up automatically closes when the process is completed.

**My Approach**

```
    if (evt.getSource() == processButton) {

            ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("img/loading.gif");
            final JLabel loaderLabel = new JLabel("loading", loading, JLabel.CENTER);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProcessFrame.this.frame.add(loaderLabel);
                }

            });
        process(); // long process
        loaderLabel.setVisible(false);
    }
```

ProcessFrame is the main JFrame which the user interacts with.

**What problem am I running into?**

The loading image never pops up (or atleast as a label). Followed some of the posts on SO, but in vain so far. Where am I getting wrong?

**Alternative**

Using SwingWorker. However, how do I know the SLEEP_TIME given the process is being executed? Or more precisely, when and how do I integrate the SwingWorker with the process() method running?

```
  SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        return null;
     }
  };
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are adding the label to the frame from a seperate Thread? Why not simply add it to the frame (without the Thread)?

Comment: Yeah, because not doing so affects EDT, and no change is observed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566311/displaying-gif-animation-in-java

Comment: Well you need to use a thread that sychronizes properly with your GUI Thread. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` instead of using a regular `Thread`.

Comment: Also your blocking process runs on your GUI thread, so your GUI thread will block completely. You need to use a seperate `Thread` for your blocking process.

Comment: @TT Just tried with SwingUtilities. Didn't work, again :( Throws Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: In short: write your program to execute your blocking process (`process();` in your code) to run in a seperate `Thread`. Have the thread communicate to your form when it is completed (by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to alert the form that the process finished).

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513)

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ProcessFrame.this.frame.add(loaderLabel);
    }
});
```

is a bad idea as you are violating the single thread rules of Swing (and you never start the `Thread`)

It should be something more like...

```
ProcessFrame.this.frame.add(loaderLabel);
ProcessFrame.this.frame.revalidate();
ProcessFrame.this.frame.repaint();
```

You should then run the `process(); // long process` in a `SwingWorker`, using it's `PropertyChangeSupport` to determine when the worker has finished, as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807495/how-to-return-value-from-swingworker-class-and-use-in-other-class-and-enable-men/32819321#32819321)

Answer (score 1):

I got this resolved. So I'm posting here my solution to my own problem. Thanks to the comments earlier. Hope this helps someone who runs into same sort of problem.

```
JDialog loadingDialog = new JDialog();

public void createDialog(JDialog d) {

    JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(("img/loading.gif")));
    d.setSize(100, 100);
    d.add(l);
    d.setVisible(true);
    d.isAlwaysOnTop();
}
// other methods ... and now defining ActionPerformed method for the button below
private void processButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == processButton) {
        createDialog(dialogLoading);
        SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
        @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                process(); // this is the long process
                return true;
            }   
            protected void done() {
                boolean status;
                try {
                    status = get();
                    dialogLoading.setVisible(false);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // This is thrown if the thread's interrupted.
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // This is thrown if we throw an exception
                    // from doInBackground.
                }
            }
       };
       worker.execute();
    }
}
```